# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRjUF.png)

I was able to solve this issue using useNavigate

```
let params = useParams();
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productId = params.id;
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
  }, [dispatch, productId]);
 
  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    navigate(`/cart/${productId}?qty=${qty}`);
  };
```

but the page didn't show anything

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbFYp.png)

thank you

Comment: Have you console.logged / debugged the value of props.history before pushing to it? And does the qty you add at the end of the url contain a value?

Answer (score 0):

While you are using react functional componenets.you should use hooks

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
const App=()=>{
  const history=useHistory()
  const submit=()=>{
     history.push("/products/23")
  }
}
```

for react router v6

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
const App=()=>{
  const navigate=useNavigate()
  const submit=()=>{
     navigate("/products/23") 
  }
}
```

Comment: useHistory is not exported in v6